# Is there a way to return an error in my console app before continuing to the next prompt

Tags: c#, console-application

I have essentially the entire program written, but I am trying to make it cleaner. On the animal selection menu with options of 1, 2 , 3 or 4, I would like it to return an error immediately if another option is selected. Currently if say 5 is selected the user is prompted to first enter a name before it returns the error that it was a valid selection. I've tried rearranging the code myself and I just end up with it not working or errors. Any suggestions or help is greatly appreciated.

```
using System;

    abstract class Animal
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public abstract void Speak();
    }

    class Dog : Animal
    {
        public override void Speak()
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"The dog {Name} barks.");
        }
    }

    class Cat : Animal
    {
        public override void Speak()
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"The cat {Name} meows.");
        }
    }

    class Pig : Animal
    {
        public override void Speak()
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"The pig {Name} oinks.");
        }
    }

    class Cow : Animal
    {
        public override void Speak()
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"The cow {Name} moos.");
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Animal[] animals = new Animal[100];
            int animalCount = 0;
            var menuChoice = "";

            while (menuChoice != "3")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Select an option:");
                Console.WriteLine("1. Enter an animal");
                Console.WriteLine("2. Have all animals speak");
                Console.WriteLine("3. Exit");
                menuChoice = Console.ReadLine();

                switch (menuChoice)
                {
                    case "1":
                        if (animalCount >= 100)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Maximum number of animals reached.");
                            break;
                        }

                        Console.WriteLine("Select an animal:");
                        Console.WriteLine("1. Dog");
                        Console.WriteLine("2. Cat");
                        Console.WriteLine("3. Pig");
                        Console.WriteLine("4. Cow");
                        var animalChoice = Console.ReadLine();

                        Console.WriteLine("Enter the desired animal's name:");
                        var animalName = Console.ReadLine();

                        Animal animal = null;
                        switch (animalChoice)
                        {
                            case "1":
                                animals[animalCount] = new Dog { Name = animalName };
                                animalCount++;
                                Console.WriteLine($"Added a dog named {animalName}.");
                                break;
                            case "2":
                                animals[animalCount] = new Cat { Name = animalName };
                                animalCount++;
                                Console.WriteLine($"Added a cat named {animalName}.");
                                break;
                            case "3":
                                animals[animalCount] = new Pig { Name = animalName };
                                animalCount++;
                                Console.WriteLine($"Added a pig named {animalName}.");
                                break;
                            case "4":
                                animals[animalCount] = new Cow { Name = animalName };
                                animalCount++;
                                Console.WriteLine($"Added a cow named {animalName}.");
                                break;
                            default:
                                Console.WriteLine("That was not a valid animal selection, please choose again from the menu above.");
                                continue;
                        }
                        if (animal != null)
                        {
                            animals[animalCount] = animal;
                            animalCount++;
                        }

                        break;
                    case "2":
                        if (animalCount == 0)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("There are currently no assigned animals that can speak.");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            for (int i = 0; i < animalCount; i++)
                            {
                                animals[i].Speak();
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    case "3":
                        Console.WriteLine("Thank you for using Animal Farm");
                        break;
                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("Invalid selection, please choose an option from the menu above.");
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried rearranging the code as well as error searching through google.

Comment: Change code to enter animal name before the type of animal.  Then add while loop after entering animal name (before type) until a valid entry is made.

Comment: Take a look at [Spectre.Console](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Spectre.Console/0.46.1-preview.0.18) [SelectionPrompt](https://spectreconsole.net/prompts/selection) which produces a menu that means the user can only select valid options. To visualize a proper menu see the following [article](https://dev.to/karenpayneoregon/console-applications-in-c-6pg)

Answer (score 0):

Copied your code. First of all, you have extra one closing curly brace. Secondly, jdweng already gave a note on what should be done. Implementing this may be not a big deal, but hope this helps.

```
namespace ConsoleApp1 // note: actual namespace depends on the project name
{
    abstract class Animal
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public abstract void Speak();
    }

    class Dog : Animal
    {
        public override void Speak()
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"The dog {Name} barks.");
        }
    }

    class Cat : Animal
    {
        public override void Speak()
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"The cat {Name} meows.");
        }
    }

    class Pig : Animal
    {
        public override void Speak()
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"The pig {Name} oinks.");
        }
    }

    class Cow : Animal
    {
        public override void Speak()
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"The cow {Name} moos.");
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Animal[] animals = new Animal[100];
            int animalCount = 0;
            var menuChoice = "";

            while (menuChoice != "3")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Select an option:");
                Console.WriteLine("1. Enter an animal");
                Console.WriteLine("2. Have all animals speak");
                Console.WriteLine("3. Exit");
                menuChoice = Console.ReadLine();

                switch (menuChoice)
                {
                    case "1":
                        if (animalCount >= 100)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Maximum number of animals reached.");
                            break;
                        }

                        // enter animals name before its type
                        Console.WriteLine("Enter the desired animal's name:");
                        var animalName = Console.ReadLine();

                        // add bool variable which tells if animals type was valid, false by default
                        var validEntry = false;
                        Animal animal = null;

                        // while loop where you keep entering animals type until it was valid. When valid type is entered, validEntry becomes true and while loop is finished
                        while (!validEntry)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Select an animal:");
                            Console.WriteLine("1. Dog");
                            Console.WriteLine("2. Cat");
                            Console.WriteLine("3. Pig");
                            Console.WriteLine("4. Cow");
                            var animalChoice = Console.ReadLine();

                            switch (animalChoice)
                            {
                                case "1":
                                    animals[animalCount] = new Dog { Name = animalName };
                                    animalCount++;
                                    Console.WriteLine($"Added a dog named {animalName}.");
                                    // thats where you need assign true to validEntry
                                    validEntry = true;
                                    break;
                                case "2":
                                    animals[animalCount] = new Cat { Name = animalName };
                                    animalCount++;
                                    Console.WriteLine($"Added a cat named {animalName}.");
                                    validEntry = true;
                                    break;
                                case "3":
                                    animals[animalCount] = new Pig { Name = animalName };
                                    animalCount++;
                                    Console.WriteLine($"Added a pig named {animalName}.");
                                    validEntry = true;
                                    break;
                                case "4":
                                    animals[animalCount] = new Cow { Name = animalName };
                                    animalCount++;
                                    Console.WriteLine($"Added a cow named {animalName}.");
                                    validEntry = true;
                                    break;
                                // if entry is invalid just print the error message and continue the while loop
                                default:
                                    Console.WriteLine("That was not a valid animal selection, please choose again from the menu above.");
                                    continue;
                            }
                        }
                        if (animal != null)
                        {
                            animals[animalCount] = animal;
                            animalCount++;
                        }
                        break;

                    case "2":
                        if (animalCount == 0)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("There are currently no assigned animals that can speak.");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            for (int i = 0; i < animalCount; i++)
                            {
                                animals[i].Speak();
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    case "3":
                        Console.WriteLine("Thank you for using Animal Farm");
                        break;
                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("Invalid selection, please choose an option from the menu above.");
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```